# how to copy table rows in alternate table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to swap two table rows using jquery, I already did this using javascript but don't know how to do this using jquery.

I did this

```js
function addTable1(val)
{
 var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length),
 cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0),
 value = val;

 cell1.innerHTML = value;
 clickTable2();
 clickTable1();
}

function clickTable1()
{
 for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
 {
  table.rows[i].onclick = function()
  {
   rIndex = this.rowIndex;
   data = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
   addTable2(data);
   removeSelectedRow();
  };
 }
}

function clickTable2()
{
 for(var i = 1; i < table2.rows.length; i++)
 {
  table2.rows[i].onclick = function()
  {
   rIndex2 = this.rowIndex;
   data = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
   addTable1(data);
   removeSelectedRow2();
  };
 }
}

function addTable2(val)
{
 var newRow = table2.insertRow(table.length),
 cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0),
 value = val;

 cell1.innerHTML = val;
 clickTable1();
 clickTable2();
}

function removeSelectedRow()
{
 table.deleteRow(rIndex);
}

function removeSelectedRow2()
{
 table2.deleteRow(rIndex2);
}

var rIndex, table = document.getElementById("table");
var rIndex2, table2 = document.getElementById("table2");
var data1, data2;

clickTable1();
clickTable2();
```

```css
.grid {
    width: 600px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 50px 50px 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 2px solid #cbcbcb;
    box-shadow: 10px 15px 5px #cbcbcb;
}

.container {
 overflow: hidden
}

.tab { 
 float: left;
}

.tab-2 {
 margin-left: 50px 
}
.tab-2 input {
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 10px
}

tr {
 transition:all .25s ease-in-out
}
tr:hover {
 background-color:#EEE;cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>add row/column</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="tab tab-1">
   <table id="table" border="1">
    <tr>
     <th>table1 text</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>A1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>B2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>C3</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="tab tab-2">
    <table id="table2" border="1">
     <tr>
      <th>table2 text</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>1A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>2B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>3C</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <script>
  var rIndex, table = document.getElementById("table");
 </script>

 <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In this code, if you click on a element of table one then that element will copy to another table and also delete from the previous table. I need to do it with jquery. Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the demo using jquery: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/KeoQOE

```
$(document).on('click','#table tr, #table2 tr',function(e){
  console.log($(this).parents('table'))
  $('table').not($(this).parents('table')).append('<tr>'+$(this).html()+'</tr>');
  $('table').find(this).remove();
})
```

Comment: this is correct but not repeated. after table1 content shifted to table2, its not shifting back to table1. like my code do

Answer (score 0):

Here I have updated your code into jQuery. Hope this is what you expected.

```js
function clickTable1() {
    table.on('click', 'tr :not(:first)', function() {
        rIndex = $(this).index();
        table2.find('tr:last').after(`<tr><td>${$(this).text()}</dt></tr>`);
        $(this).remove();
    });
}

function clickTable2() {
    table2.on('click', 'tr :not(:first)', function() {
        rIndex = $(this).index();
        table.find('tr:last').after(`<tr><td>${$(this).text()}</dt></tr>`);
        $(this).remove();
    });
}

var table = $("#table");
var table2 = $("#table2");

clickTable1();
clickTable2();
```

```css
.grid {
    width: 600px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 50px 50px 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 2px solid #cbcbcb;
    box-shadow: 10px 15px 5px #cbcbcb;
}

.container {
 overflow: hidden
}

.tab { 
 float: left;
}

.tab-2 {
 margin-left: 50px 
}
.tab-2 input {
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 10px
}

tr {
 transition:all .25s ease-in-out
}
tr:hover {
 background-color:#EEE;cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div class="container">
  <div class="tab tab-1">
   <table id="table" border="1">
    <tr>
     <th>table1 text</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>A1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>B2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>C3</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="tab tab-2">
    <table id="table2" border="1">
     <tr>
      <th>table2 text</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>1A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>2B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>3C</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('table').on('click','td',function(){

    var currentTable = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
    var anotherTable = (currentTable === 'table') ? 'table2' : 'table' ;

    $("<tr><td>"+$(this).html()+"</td></tr>").appendTo("#"+anotherTable);
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();

  })
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('table').on('click','td',function(){
    var currentTable = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
    var anotherTable = (currentTable === 'table') ? 'table2' : 'table' ;
    $("<tr><td>"+$(this).html()+"</td></tr>").appendTo("#"+anotherTable);
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  })
})
```

```css
.container { overflow: hidden; }

.tab { float: left; }

.tab-2 { margin-left: 50px; }

.tab-2 input { display: block; margin-bottom: 10px; }

tr { transition:all .25s ease-in-out; }

tr:hover { background-color:#EEE; cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab tab-1">
    <table id="table" border="1">
      <tr><th>table1 text</th></tr>
   <tr><td>A1</td></tr>
   <tr><td>B2</td></tr>
   <tr><td>C3</td></tr>
 </table>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="tab tab-2">
   <table id="table2" border="1">
     <tr><th>table2 text</th></tr>
     <tr><td>1A</td></tr>
     <tr><td>2B</td></tr>
     <tr><td>3C</td></tr>
   </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can delegate click event like this

```js
$("#table").delegate('tr', 'click', function () {
        $("#table2").append("<tr>" + $(this).html() + "</tr>");
        $(this).remove();
    });
    $("#table2").delegate('tr', 'click', function () {
        $("#table").append("<tr>" + $(this).html() + "</tr>");
        $(this).remove();
    });
```

```css
.grid {
    width: 600px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 50px 50px 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 2px solid #cbcbcb;
    box-shadow: 10px 15px 5px #cbcbcb;
}

.container {
 overflow: hidden
}

.tab { 
 float: left;
}

.tab-2 {
 margin-left: 50px 
}
.tab-2 input {
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 10px
}

tr {
 transition:all .25s ease-in-out
}
tr:hover {
 background-color:#EEE;cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>add row/column</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="tab tab-1">
   <table id="table" border="1">
    <tr>
     <th>table1 text</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>A1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>B2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>C3</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="tab tab-2">
    <table id="table2" border="1">
     <tr>
      <th>table2 text</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>1A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>2B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>3C</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>


 <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```